# pg_search and localization in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, locale, pg-search

I am using pg_search and have some trouble with localization.
I have shop_item model that have title1, title2, description1, description2 attributes. Depends from language I am using combination of title1 + description1, or title2 + description2 
In application controller i have a method that set locale:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
        before_action :set_locale
    private

        def set_locale
            I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
        end
end
```

ShopItemsController:

```
def index
    if params[:search].present?
      @shop_items = ShopItem.search_for_items(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 32).order('created_at DESC')
    else
      @shop_items = ShopItem.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 32).order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end
```

And in my shop_items/index.html.erb  I have:

```
          <%= form_tag shop_items_path, :method => 'get'  do %>
          <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], autofocus: true,  type: "text", placeholder: 'search for messages'%>
          <%= submit_tag "search", type: "submit"%>
          <% end %>  

</br>
<% if current_page?(locale: :ua)%>
  <div class="row">    
    <% @shop_items.each do |si| %>

        <div class="col m3 ">
          <div class="card hoverable">
            <div class="card-image">
              <%= image_tag si.shop_image.url(:large) %>        
            </div>
            <div class="card-content"-->
              <span class="card-title truncate"><td><%= si.title1 %></td></span>
              <p><%= t(:price)%>: <%= si.price%></p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
              <%= link_to t(:details), shop_item_path(si) %>
              <%= link_to t(:edit), edit_shop_item_path(si) if current_user.present? and current_user.admin? %>
              <%= link_to t(:destroy), si, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } if current_user.present? and current_user.admin? %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

If I am going to shop_items_path I see in my browser next url as default:

```
http://localhost:3000/shop_items?locale=ua
```

I can see all my shop_items, but if I am removing locale from url, like:

```
  http://localhost:3000/shop_items
```

All items are disappear 
When I am using search I have url like:

```
http://localhost:3000/shop_items?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=item&commit=search
```

As you can see locale is missing, as the result I can see any shop_items after search.

My question is how to store current locale and include it in search query?

Thanks for any solution!

UPDATED:
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root :to => 'shop_items#index'
    resources :shopping_contacts
    resources :cart_items

```
resources :shopping_carts do
    #resources :contact_infos
    resources :shopping_contacts
    resources :cart_items
    resources :cart_confirms
end
resources :shop_items do
    resources :cart_items
end

resources :contact_us
resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :index, :destroy]  

get 'password_resets/new'

get 'password_resets/edit'

get 'sessions/new'
get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]


get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'  
resources :users

resources :main_shots
```

end

Comment: Can you post your routes please?

Comment: @RonanLouarn sure, updated. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thinks for update, maybe you should follow these steps.

1st nest yours routes in  'scope '(:locale)', locale: /en|es/ do:' like that.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 
 scope '(:locale)', locale: /en|es/ do


  root :to => 'shop_items#index' 
  resources :shopping_contacts 
  resources :cart_items

  resources :shopping_carts do
    #resources :contact_infos
    resources :shopping_contacts
    resources :cart_items
    resources :cart_confirms
  end

  resources :shop_items do
    resources :cart_items
  end

  resources :contact_us
  resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :index, :destroy]  

  get 'password_resets/new'

  get 'password_resets/edit'

  get 'sessions/new'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]


  get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'  
  resources :users

  resources :main_shots
 end
end
```

2nd step add this method like that in application_controller.rb:

```
  before_action :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params.fetch(:locale, I18n.default_locale).to_sym
  end

  def default_url_options
    { locale: I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale ? nil : I18n.locale }
  end
```

Last step have you set defautl local in application.rb ?:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
```

Give me your feedback, good luck.

Comment: No problem ;) , have fun